# telit cell modem http server

Tags: http, modem

I need to implement an http server on a device that will be installed at a remote location and  acessible through a cell modem. I am experience in embedded systems but I'm new to cell modems.

I was originally using this cell modem: http://www.janus-rc.com/HSPA910cf.html (based on a Telit HE910 module) for SMS alerts but now need to implement the http server functionailty.

I am not sure whether this cell modem supports the http server functionality and cannot seem to find much on the topic.

Would appreciate if anyone with experience in cell modems can shed some light on this.

Comment: Does the modem need to make outgoing connections or accept incoming connections?

Comment: It took me a a while to figure out your question! Maybe you could some information on what you've tried and what the issues are?

Comment: Well true my question is a bit generic as I'm looking for a starting point rather than a need a specific answer. The basically the question is: can the HSPA910CF be used as a web server ? I need to accept incoming TCP connections on port 80 and serve a web page through the cell modem to the connecting client. It that possible with this modem ? It can open a socket in listen mode need the opinion of someone with more experience in cell modems.

Answer (score 2):

The HE910 does not have any sort of built-in HTTP server, but you can still implement your own.

If you look at the documentation ([Telit_HE910_UE910_AT_Commands_Reference_Guide_r5](http://www.telit.com/module/infopool/download.php?id=4092)), you'll see that the HE910 has support for TCP, allowing you to use AT commands to make and receive socket connections.

It even appears (see [Telit_Easy_Script_Python_2.7_r3](http://www.telit.com/module/infopool/download.php?id=5752)) that the HE910 supports on-board Python with the `socket` module, so you should be able to implement a small HTTP server without even requiring a host to drive it.

Comment: thanks Gabe, so basically if I open a socket using AT#SL listening on port 80 and accept a client connection then I should be able to get raw HTTP request which are then passed to the host processor over serial (let's ignore the python option for now as I would prefer to use the host processor) and I need to parse them and send out the HTTP response. Is that correct ?